# Possible combination of a nested list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

If I have a list of lists and want to find all the possible combination from each different indices, how could I do that?

For example:

```
list_of_lists = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

I want to find

```
all_possibility = [[1, 5, 9], [1, 8, 6], [4, 2, 9], [4, 8, 3], [7, 2, 6], [7, 5, 3]]
```

where

- [1,5,9]: 1 is 1st element of [1, 2, 3], 5 is 2nd element of [4, 5, 6], 9 is 3rd element of [7, 8, 9].
- [1,8,6]: 1 is 1st element of [1, 2, 3], 8 is 2nd element of [7, 8, 9], 6 is 3rd element of [4, 5, 6].

and so on.

(Edited) Note: I would like the result to be in the same order as the original element of the list. [1, 8, 6] but not [1, 6, 8] because 8 is the 2nd element of [7, 8, 9].

Comment: Hi @Raj Thanks for the prompt response. I have tried list(itertools.product(* list_of_lists)), but it gives me ALL the possible cases without considering the indices. I am thinking to try multiple for loops, but I don't think it is a good idea (or is it?). There must be a better way in python. I have scratched my head for all day. Any keyword/post I should look up? Thanks.

Comment: @udothemath1984, is it case for only 3 input sublists?

Comment: Hi @RomanPerekhrest Not necessary. It might be list_of_lists = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]]. In this case, all_possibility would be [[1, 4], [1, 6], [1, 8], [3, 2], [3, 6], [3, 8], [5, 2], [5, 4], [5, 8], [7, 2], [7, 4], [7, 6]]. If I know how to solve the case with 3 subllists, I should be able to figure this out (I assume). Thanks.

Comment: @udothemath1984, so aren't you looking for something like Mr Geek answered?

Comment: Nope. I need the ones with different indices from other list in the nested list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have to consider the indices as well. For example, `(1, 4, 7)` is excluded because `1`, and `4` both are the 1st element from the list of the lists (from `[1, 2, 3]` and `[4, 5, 6]`). And actually `(1, 4, 7)` all of them are from the first component of the nested list. I need the cases with all the different indices.

So you actually just want to get the possible permutations of a “list selector” for each index in the output, i.e. these are what you are trying to get:

```
>>> list(itertools.permutations(range(3), 3))
[(0, 1, 2), (0, 2, 1), (1, 0, 2), (1, 2, 0), (2, 0, 1), (2, 1, 0)]
```

And once you have that, you just need to translate into your `list_of_lists` where you access each index from the specified sublist:

```
>>> [[list_of_lists[k][i] for i, k in enumerate(comb)] for comb in itertools.permutations(range(3), 3)]
[[1, 5, 9], [1, 8, 6], [4, 2, 9], [4, 8, 3], [7, 2, 6], [7, 5, 3]]
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks @poke. It is very readable and the results remain the order of all the possible cases. It is exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 6):

What you're looking for is the Cartesian product, in Python `itertools.product`:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list_of_lists = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
>>> all_possibility = list(itertools.product(*list_of_lists))
>>> print(all_possibility)
[(1, 4, 7), (1, 4, 8), (1, 4, 9), (1, 5, 7), (1, 5, 8), (1, 5, 9), (1, 6, 7), (1, 6, 8),
 (1, 6, 9), (2, 4, 7), (2, 4, 8), (2, 4, 9), (2, 5, 7), (2, 5, 8), (2, 5, 9), (2, 6, 7),
 (2, 6, 8), (2, 6, 9), (3, 4, 7), (3, 4, 8), (3, 4, 9), (3, 5, 7), (3, 5, 8), (3, 5, 9),
 (3, 6, 7), (3, 6, 8), (3, 6, 9)]
```

If you want permutations based on the indices rather than the values, you can use `itertools.combinations` to get the possible indices, then use those indices to get the respective values from the sub-lists, like this:

```
>>> list_of_lists = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
>>> length = 3
>>> all_indices = list(itertools.permutations(range(length), length))
>>> all_possibility = [[l[i] for l,i in zip(list_of_lists, indices)] for indices in all_indices]
>>> print(all_possibility)
[[1, 5, 9], [1, 6, 8], [2, 4, 9], [2, 6, 7], [3, 4, 8], [3, 5, 7]]
```

Comment: Not entirely. I have to consider the indices as well. For example, (1, 4, 7) is excluded because 1, and 4 both are the 1st element from the list of the lists (from [1, 2, 3] and [4, 5, 6]). And actually (1, 4, 7) all of them are from the first component of the nested list. I need the cases with all the different indices. Thanks.

Comment: @udothemath1984 I updated my answer with a solution to your specific problem.

Comment: Thanks @Mr Geek I learn a lot from the thread. I need the results to be in the same order of where it comes from. For instance, [1, 8, 6] but not [1, 6, 8] since 8 is the second element from the list [7, 8, 9].

Answer (score 0):

In a spirit of @poke's approach, here is the cases for number of elements differ than the number of the list in the lists. (Previously, there are 3 elements in individual list where 3 sub-lists in the list).

```
list_of_lists = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]]
```

We expect every (0, 1) pairs from the list of lists, or

```
all_possibility = [[1, 4], [1, 6], [1, 8], [3, 2], [3, 6], [3, 8], \
                   [5, 2], [5, 4], [5, 8], [7, 2], [7, 4], [7, 6]]
```

The code:

```
permutation_cases = list(itertools.permutations(range(2), 2))
select_from = list(itertools.combinations(range(len(list_of_lists)), 2))

all_possibility = []
for selecting_index in select_from:
        selected = [list_of_lists[i] for i in selecting_index ]
        cases = list([selected[k][i] for i, k in enumerate(comb)] for comb in permutation_cases)
        for item in cases:
            all_possibility.append(item)
print(all_possibility)
```